# getting all true keys from object using angular and/or underscore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an object in Angular looking like this:

```
$scope.addEmployeeDepartments={ 5066549580791808=true, 6192449487634432=true, 7192449487634432=false}
```

How do I generate a comma-separated string like this

```
var ids="5066549580791808, 6192449487634432"
```

containing all the keys which are true ?

Btw, I am using underscore.js in other parts of my solution, so I don't know if that makes it easier.

thanks

Thomas

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you post a live demo to reproduce the problem? Also that doesn't look like valid syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) in one pass:

```
var collect_trues_in = function(a, v, k) {
    if(v)
        a.push(k);
    return a;
};
var csv = _($scope.addEmployeeDepartments).reduce(collect_trues_in, [ ]).join(', ');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6CEZW/